# Home and Back buttons press: effect not immediate

Tags: hardware, homescreen

I introduced a `Thread.sleep` in different points of an Android application. The objective is to give me enough time to press either `Home` or `Back` at these exact points in code.

When I press one of these buttons at the sleep instruction, the button action is not carried immediately and in some cases additional instructions of the client application are executed. That is, the thread is sleeping, I press `Home`, and the client application still processes a few lines of code (after the sleep) before returning to the Home screen.

Why does this happen?

.

To give a more clear picture of the problem, consider the following block of code:

```
instruction 1;
instruction 2;
instruction 3;
Thread.sleep(8000);
instruction 4;
instruction 5;
instruction 6;
instruction 7;
...
instruction N;
```

`Home` or `Back` are pressed at the sleep, but the application might still execute a couple of instructions, say up to 6 or 7, before actually terminating.

[edit] I want to add that the application includes several AsyncTasks, and that I introduced sleeps both inside and outside of them.

Comment: @Izzy Ah, I see. Is it possible to move the topic there or should I delete it from here and recreate it on the correct place?

Comment: You should flag this question for a moderator to move it to StackOverflow.

Comment: Thank you for moving the question.

Comment: Yepp, your request was already "in-progress" before you made it :) Good luck here!

Comment: Are you running Thread.sleep(); on the main thread?

Answer (score 0):

I think what your problem is, is that you are running `Thread.sleep()` on the main thread. This is something you don't want to do in Android or in Java (or in any other language for that matter).

In Android, the main thread should only be used to manually setup UI elements. Android automatically puts your code on the main thread when:

1. The application is starting (the `onCreate(...)` method)
2. The application received an event callback (`onTouch(...)`, `onKey(...)`)
3. You create a new Activity (`onCreate(...)` of the new Activity)

You should manually put a code block on the main thread when:

1. You are modifying the UI
2. You are manually doing an event callback (calling `onClickListener.onClick(...)`)

There are more situations but those are the most common. What you need to do is this:

```
Runnable run = new Runnable()
{
    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(...); // <- your code goes here

    }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();} // just in case of interruption
}

Thread thread = new Thread(run);
thread.start();
```

This way, the main thread won't be busy when the user wants to escape from your application. You should refrain from doing long complex operations on the main thread too, because it can cause your application to get 'laggy' with reguards to the UI.

See also: [Activity | Android Developers: runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29)

^^ that is the method you can use to change the UI elements.